# Inequality for the p norm of a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Let $1\le p < \infty$. Let $g \in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$, and $f \in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$.

Show: $\|f*g\|_p \le \|f\|_1\|g\|_p$, where $*$ indicates the convolution defined by

$$ f*g (x) := \int f(x-t) g(t)dt.$$

Here is a relevant hint, apparently:

Let $q$ be the conjugate of $p$. Note that:

$$|f*g| \le \int [|g(t)||f(x-t)|^{1/p}]|f(x-t)|^{1/q}dt,$$
then apply Holder's inequality.

I did exactly as the hint suggested, and ended up with what looked like a meaningless inequality compared to the final answer. I even took the $p$ power of both sides.

Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have - don't forget the $x$ -

$$\lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert \leqslant \int \bigl[\lvert g(t)\rvert\cdot\lvert f(x-t)\rvert^{1/p}\bigr]\cdot \lvert f(x-t)\rvert^{1/q}\,dt.$$

Applying Hölder's inequality to that yields

$$\begin{align}
\lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert &\leqslant \left(\int \lvert g(t)\rvert^p \lvert f(x-t)\rvert\,dt\right)^{1/p}\cdot \left(\int \lvert f(x-t)\rvert\,dt\right)^{1/q}\\
&= \lVert f\rVert_1^{1/q}\cdot\left(\int \lvert g(t)\rvert^p \lvert f(x-t)\rvert\,dt\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align}$$

Raising to the $p$-th power,

$$\lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert^p \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_1^{p/q}\cdot \int \lvert g(t)\rvert^p\lvert f(x-t)\rvert\,dt,$$

and integrating with respect to $x$:

$$\begin{align}
\int \lvert (f\ast g)(x)\rvert^p\,dx &\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_1^{p/q}\cdot \iint \lvert g(t)\rvert^p\lvert f(x-t)\rvert\,dt\,dx\\
&=  \lVert f\rVert_1^{p/q}\cdot \iint \lvert g(t)\rvert^p\lvert f(x-t)\rvert\,dx\,dt\tag{Fubini}\\
&= \lVert f\rVert_1^{p/q} \lVert f\rVert_1\lVert g\rVert_p^p.
\end{align}$$

Taking the $p$-th root then yields

$$\lVert f\ast g\rVert_p \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_1^{1/q+1/p}\cdot \lVert g\rVert_p,$$

which, since $\frac1q + \frac1p = 1$, is the desired result.

Comment: Why is $ \lvert g(t)\rvert\cdot\lvert f(x-t)\rvert^{1/p} $ in $ L_p $ ?

Comment: @n.e. Doesn't the Fubini/Tonelli part of the proof show that it must be in $L^p$ for a.e. $x$?

Comment: @Bungo in order to use Holders inequality in line 4 we need $ \lvert g(t)\rvert\cdot\lvert f(x-t)\rvert^{1/p}$ to be in $L_p$ so I dont think so since the fubini part comes way after

Comment: @n.e. Well, you could use Fubini at the start to show that the double integral of $|g(t)|^p |f(x-t)|$ equals $\|f\|_1 \|g\|_p^p$, which is finite, and therefore the single integral with respect to $t$ must be finite for a.e. $x$. But I think this way is also OK. Holder's inequality is still true if the RHS is infinite (or not yet known to be finite).

Comment: @Bungo Cool I got it now, you're right. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Why can't we just write $$\| f \ast g \|_{p} = \| g \ast f\|_{p} = \left\| \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(\cdot - y) f(y) dy \right\|_p \overset{\textrm{(M)}}{\le}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left\| g(\cdot - y) f(y) \right\|_p dy,$$ where (M) is Minkowski's inequality and as $\left\| g(\cdot - y) f(y) \right\|_p = | f(y) | \| g(\cdot - y) \|_{p} = | f(y) | \| g \|_{p}$ by the invariance of the lebesgue measure conclude that $$\int_{R^n} \left\| g(\cdot - y) f(y) \right\|_p dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} | f(y) | \| g \|_{p} dy = \| f \|_1 \| g \|_p$$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik If you have a version of Minkowski's inequality that directly justifies the step (M), then you can just write it that way. But I don't know a reference for that, seems to be rarely done.

Comment: @DanielFischer If thought its just \begin{align}\left\| \int g(\cdot - y) f(y) dy \right\|_p^{p} & = \int \left| \int g(x - y) f(y) dy \right|^p dx \overset{\triangle \ne_p}{\le} \int \int | g(x - y) |^p | f(y) |^p dy dx \\ & \overset{\textrm{(F)}}{=} \int \int | g(x - y) |^p | f(y) |^p dx dy = \int \| g (\cdot - y) f(y) \|_p^{p} dy,\end{align} where (F) is Fubini and $\triangle \ne_p$ the "$p$-triangle inequality" or better Minkowski's .

Comment: @DanielFischer I see that what I just wrote is a bit fishy because we'd have to take $p$-th roots. But the argument I was trying to make seems to be a lot like in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556580/545914). Is this answer not correct?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I take it that "a bit fishy" means you're aware that as written it's not quite correct, though close. (Concentrating on the idea and getting a few details not quite correct, I guess.) The argument in the answer you linked is correct (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski%27s_integral_inequality)). But that form of Minkowski's inequality isn't very widely taught, so for the convolution case quite often the way using the more familiar Hölder inequality is taken. (And of course, it's the way the hint mentioned in the question aims for.)