# Does Mollification Convergence in Lp still hold for Sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose that $f_n \to f \in L^p(\mathbf{R}^N)$ and $\varphi_{\frac{1}{n}}$ is the standard mollifier $\varphi$ normalized to $\frac{1}{n}$. Do we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * f_n - f_n \|_{L^p(\mathbf{R}^N)} = 0?
$$
I know that the result is standard if we do not have sequence and I hypothesize the above follows from the standard result. It seems like we should just be adding and subtracting $f$ in the norm and use the middle-man trick and triangle inequality. However, is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * f_n - f \| = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g_n=f_n-f$. Then by [1] and the hypothesis $\| \  g_n  \|_p \to 0$, we have
$$\| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * g_n  \|_p \le \|\varphi_{\frac{1}{n}}\|_1 \cdot  \|   g_n  \|_p  = \| \  g_n  \|_p \longrightarrow 0 $$
as $ n \to \infty$. Thus, by the triangle inequality in $L^p$,
\begin{eqnarray} \| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * f_n - f_n \|_p &=&\| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * (f+g_n) - f-g_n \|_p \\ &\le& \| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * f - f  \|_p + \| \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} * g_n  \|_p+ \| g_n \|_p  \; \longrightarrow 0 
\end{eqnarray}
as $ n \to \infty$.

[1] [Inequality for the p norm of a convolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722689/inequality-for-the-p-norm-of-a-convolution)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only $f$, add and subtract $f+\varphi_{1/n}*f$, so that matters are reduced to showing
$$
\| \varphi_{1/n}* (f_n-f)\|_p \to 0.
$$
For this, use Minkowski's integral inequality to get
$$
\| \varphi_{1/n}* (f_n-f)\|_p \leq \| f_n-f\|_p.
$$